# How to make rating stars in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-rating

I am creating a survey app using React js and getting all the data from an API using the fetch method. I already make the rating survey page and wanted to make that stars working. And I have tried rating stars with png image and it is working fine for 1 question. But when I add another question with that rating stars it's not working.

**This is what I tried**
[image]

**This is my code**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import fullStarSrc from "../img/highlightedStar.png";
import emptyStarSrc from "../img/star.png";

export default class testPage extends Component {
  state = {
    qtemp3: [
      { idsurveyquestion: "22", question: "Taste of the food?" },
      { idsurveyquestion: "23", question: "Quality of the food?" },
      { idsurveyquestion: "24", question: "Speed Of delivery?" },
      { idsurveyquestion: "25", question: "The accuracy of the order?" },
      { idsurveyquestion: "26", question: "How is our service?" },
    ],
  };


  rate = (event) => {
    const { id } = event.target;
    var i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      if (i <= parseInt(id)) {
        document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", fullStarSrc);
      } else {
        document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", emptyStarSrc);
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { qtemp3 } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div class="bg">
          <div class="bg_img1"></div>
          <div class="heading1">
            <center>
              <h2 class="head1">Please Rate Us</h2>
            </center>
          </div>
          <center>
            <div>
              {qtemp3.map((item) => (
                <>
                  <p key={item.idsurveyquestion}>{item.question}</p>
                  <div>
                    <img onClick={this.rate} class="star" id="1" src={emptyStarSrc} />
                    <img onClick={this.rate} class="star" id="2" src={emptyStarSrc} />
                    <img onClick={this.rate} class="star" id="3" src={emptyStarSrc} />
                    <img onClick={this.rate} class="star" id="4" src={emptyStarSrc} />
                    <img onClick={this.rate} class="star" id="5" src={emptyStarSrc} />
                  </div>
                </>
              ))}
            </div>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now I need to make all the stars to working as the first question. How can I fix This problem? Please help me.

Comment: Two things stand out: 1. don't mix React with directly manipulating the `document`, there's no need for that and it's likely to cause problems; and 2. you have nothing right now to tell you _which_ item you're rating, and have multiple items with the same `id`.

Comment: Ok, sir. Here I wanted to display the questions data from API and Each question should have a rating star field. I want to make all the rating stars to be working. I need to rate all 5 questions and need to send that data into the database.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But currently you don't store that information for other use anyway (because you directly manipulate the DOM instead) and apparently haven't considered how to keep track of multiple ratings at all. Maybe start with this: what if clicking a rating updated the state for the relevant item, then the images were rendered _based on that state_?

Comment: Actually, I am new to react and I don't know a lot of things and the methods. If there is a way to do it, please help me with the new way.

Comment: I think I have done: _"what if clicking a rating updated the state"_. Have a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html, and the rest of the introductory documentation (particularly relevant here would be _Forms_ and _Thinking in React_). SO is **not** a replacement for learning the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest solution would be crete an index for `img`s that is a combination of a progressive and `item`'s `idsurveyquestion`. So:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import fullStarSrc from "../img/highlightedStar.png";
import emptyStarSrc from "../img/star.png";

export default class testPage extends Component {
  state = {
    qtemp3: [
      { idsurveyquestion: "22", question: "Taste of the food?" },
      { idsurveyquestion: "23", question: "Quality of the food?" },
      { idsurveyquestion: "24", question: "Speed Of delivery?" },
      { idsurveyquestion: "25", question: "The accuracy of the order?" },
      { idsurveyquestion: "26", question: "How is our service?" },
    ],
  };


  rate = (event, item) => {
    const { id } = event.target;
    var i;

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      if (parseInt(i + item.idsurveyquestion) <= parseInt(id)) {
        document.getElementById(parseInt(i + item.idsurveyquestion)).setAttribute("src", fullStarSrc);
      } else {
        document.getElementById(parseInt(i + item.idsurveyquestion)).setAttribute("src", emptyStarSrc);
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { qtemp3 } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div class="bg">
          <div class="bg_img1"></div>
          <div class="heading1">
            <center>
              <h2 class="head1">Please Rate Us</h2>
            </center>
          </div>
          <center>
            <div>
              {qtemp3.map((item) => (
                <>
                  <p key={item.idsurveyquestion}>{item.question}</p>
                  <div>
                    <img onClick={(event) => this.rate(event, item)} class="star" id={"1" + item.idsurveyquestion} src={emptyStarSrc} />
                    <img onClick={(event) => this.rate(event, item)} class="star" id={"2" + item.idsurveyquestion} src={emptyStarSrc} />
                    <img onClick={(event) => this.rate(event, item)} class="star" id={"3" + item.idsurveyquestion} src={emptyStarSrc} />
                    <img onClick={(event) => this.rate(event, item)} class="star" id={"4" + item.idsurveyquestion} src={emptyStarSrc} />
                    <img onClick={(event) => this.rate(event, item)} class="star" id={"5" + item.idsurveyquestion} src={emptyStarSrc} />
                  </div>
                </>
              ))}
            </div>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

There are some notes: as @jonrsharpe said on comment, DOM manipulation in React di discouraged and you should make your DOM dynamic using state variable.

So in this case you should create a state variable that is a collection of boolean array:

```
  state = {
    qtemp3: [
      { id:0, idsurveyquestion: "22", question: "Taste of the food?" },
      { id:1, idsurveyquestion: "23", question: "Quality of the food?" },
      { id:2, idsurveyquestion: "24", question: "Speed Of delivery?" },
      { id:3, idsurveyquestion: "25", question: "The accuracy of the order?" },
      { id:4, idsurveyquestion: "26", question: "How is our service?" },
    ],
    rating: [[false, false, false, false, false],
             [false, false, false, false, false],
             [false, false, false, false, false],
             [false, false, false, false, false],
             [false, false, false, false, false]]
  };
```

Then with `rate` funciotn you set to true all the elements for the corresponding array, and finally condition html with `rating` state:

```
  rate = (event, item) => {
    const { id } = event.target;
    var i;
    let ratingCopy = [...this.state.rating]

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      if (i <= parseInt(id)) {
        ratingCopy[item.id][i - 1] = true
      } else {
        ratingCopy[item.id][i - 1] = false
      }
    }

    this.setState({ rating: ratingCopy })
  };

render() {
    const { qtemp3 } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div class="bg">
          <div class="bg_img1"></div>
          <div class="heading1">
            <center>
              <h2 class="head1">Please Rate Us</h2>
            </center>
          </div>
          <center>
            <div>
              {qtemp3.map((item) => (
                <>
                  <p key={item.idsurveyquestion}>{item.question}</p>
                  <div>
                    <img onClick={(event) => this.rate(event, item)} class="star" id="1" src={this.state.rating[item.id][0] ? fullStarSrc : emptyStarSrc} />
                    <img onClick={(event) => this.rate(event, item)} class="star" id="2" src={this.state.rating[item.id][1] ? fullStarSrc : emptyStarSrc} />
                    <img onClick={(event) => this.rate(event, item)} class="star" id="3" src={this.state.rating[item.id][2] ? fullStarSrc : emptyStarSrc}/>
                    <img onClick={(event) => this.rate(event, item)} class="star" id="4" src={this.state.rating[item.id][3] ? fullStarSrc : emptyStarSrc} />
                    <img onClick={(event) => this.rate(event, item)} class="star" id="5" src={this.state.rating[item.id][4] ? fullStarSrc : emptyStarSrc} />
                  </div>
                </>
              ))}
            </div>
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try this out. And one thing, How can I store the star rating value for each question ( for store data in database)?

Comment: @Sidath You can store rate in `rate` function just after `this.setState({ rating: ratingCopy })`. You have all teh information you need: `item` (that contains the question id) and `rating` (count true values in `ratingCopy[item.id]`). You get these info and call the api to store question's rating.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this Approach Also,

```js
 {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((el) => {
                    return (
                    <React.Fragment>
                    el <= ratings ? (
                                        <StarIcon fill="#000000" />
                                    ) : (
                                        <StarIcon fill="#ffffff" />
                                    )}
                                </React.Fragment>
                            );
                        })}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).